# Scala - compiles when casting generic type without bounds to a pattern assignment

Tags: scala

I just had this bug a few days ago and didn't quite understand why the Scala compiler allows this code to compile:

```
class Foo[K] {

  def bar(k: K) = {
    val Seq(x) = k // Why isn't the compiler complaining about this?
    val Array(y) = k
    val List(z) = k
    println(k)
  }

}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val foo = new Foo[String]()
    foo.bar("hello")
  }
}
```

Obviously K can be whatever, and has no implicits or whatever that says that it's a Seq, List or Array. Why isn't the compiler finding this bug? I find it pretty absurd and very un-typesafe. I'm using Scala 2.10.3.

Comment: The generics are a distraction, the same problem exists without them: `val k: Any = "hi"; val Array(l) = k`

Comment: It's more problematic with the generics. As one of comments to the issue says, once you've explicitly told the compiler that the value is of Any type, complaining that it's not using its actual type afterwards seems odd. But the generics case doesn't have that problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that it's pretty awful. There's an open bug: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5898 .

Comment: Ok, there seems to be a lot more discussion there, thank you for your answer!